# Cross platform process enumerator for Python?

Tags: python, process-management

I need a cross-platform module which allows me to enumerate processes on the machine. It needs to work on Windows and Unix, and get things like PID and Process Names.

*Is there such module?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil) should work nicely for this.

"psutil is a module providing an interface for retrieving information on all running processes and system utilization (CPU, memory) in a portable way by using Python, implementing many functionalities offered by command line tools like ps, top, kill, lsof and netstat."

Comment: the correct url is http://code.google.com/p/psutil/ it supports python  2.4 to 3.2